# .Net Core application exit code. Different behaviour on Linux (RHEL 7)

Tags: .net-core, rhel, exit-code

I seem unable to set the exit code of a dotnet core console application such that the expected behaviour is observed on RHEL7. I am using dotnet 2.0.3.

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Environment.Exit(12345);
        }
    }
}
```

On windows, the error level is set correctly when executing the program with

```
dotnet HelloWorld.dll
echo %errorlevel%
12345
```

On RHEL7, this is not what is seen

```
dotnet HelloWorld.dll
echo $?
57
```

I have tried various ways to return an exit code (setting the Environment.ExitCode property, returning an integer from the program) but have had no success.

I will try a test on the latest dotnet core version (2.1.302) as soon as possible but posting this question in the meantime.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I found the problem in the end - it was because on RHEL7, unlike Windows, the exit code/error level is restricted to being an 8 bit integer. I'll need to keep my exit codes in the range [0,255].